# Check if Exists PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context

Tags: oracle, if-statement, stored-procedures, plsql

I have cursor it selects from TableA then Fetch Loop that inserts into TableB.

I want to check if the value already exists in the TableB.

If it exists then I want to skip the insert.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE DAILY_RPT (
    v_start       IN DATE,
    v_end        IN DATE)

IS

    ao_out_no   out_pair.out_no%type;

cursor get is
SELECT ao_out_no from tableA;

BEGIN
 open get;
     LOOP
     fetch get into ao_out_no;
      EXIT WHEN get%NOTFOUND;
     if (ao_out_no = (select out_no from TableA where out_no = ao_out_no) THEN
     --DO NOTHING
     else 
        INSERT INTO TABLEB(OUT_NO) VALUES (ao_out_no);
     end if;

        END LOOP;
     close get;

END;
```

I used `IF CONDITION` however, I used variable into if condition & I am getting below.

```
PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context

if (ao_out_no = (select out_no from TableA where out_no = ao_out_no) THEN
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need cursor or PL/SQL at all:

```
INSERT INTO TABLEB(OUT_NO) 
SELECT ao_out_no 
FROM tableA ta
WHERE ... -- filtering rows
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * From TableB tb WHERE tb.OUT_NO = ta.ao_out_no);
```

Comment: I must use PL/SQL, this is only part of the PL/SQL code.

Comment: @user206168 So just wrap it with your PL/SQL procedure, but still there is no need for explicit CURSOR

Answer (score 1):

Use the following :

```
for i in (
    select out_no from TableA where out_no
)
loop
    if i.out_no = ao_out_no
    then
        -- DO NOTHING
    else 
        ...
```

or 
create a new variable named `x`, and then assign a value to it by

```
select out_no into x from TableA where out_no = ao_out_no;
```

and check returning value for `x`.

Comment: I'm sure this is on the right lines, but the cursor is missing something after `where out_no`.

Answer (score 1):

With corrected syntax, it would be something like this:

```
create or replace procedure daily_rpt
    ( v_start in date
    , v_end   in date )
as
begin
    for r in (
        select ao_out_no, 0 as exists_check
        from   tablea
    )
    loop
        select count(*) into exists_check
        from   tablea
        where  out_no = r.ao_out_no
        and    rownum = 1;

        if r.exists_check > 0 then
            --DO NOTHING
        else
            insert into tableb (out_no) values (r.ao_out_no);
        end if;

    end loop;
end;
```

However, it's inefficient to query all of the rows and then do an additional lookup for each row to decide whether you want to use it, as SQL can do that kind of thing for you. So version 2 might be something like:

```
create or replace procedure daily_rpt
    ( v_start in date
    , v_end   in date )
as
begin
    for r in (
        select ao_out_no
        from   tablea
        where  not exists
               ( select count(*)
                 from   tablea
                 where  out_no = r.ao_out_no
                 and    rownum = 1 )
    )
    loop
        insert into tableb (out_no) values (r.ao_out_no);
    end loop;
end;
```

at which point you might replace the whole loop with an `insert ... where not exists (...)` statement.